# Bypass alert "Do you want to run this application"

Tags: java, applet, security

Is there any way to convert **self signed certificate to trusted** one?

So can I by pass below alert?

[image]

I have one applet which trying to run some application on user's machine.

I am using self signed jar.

Comment: You basically want to do what viruses want to: run executable code without any sort of assurance, or knowledge from the user side, through the web. Do you think this is reasonable?

Comment: Is there any way to convert self signed certificate to trusted one?

Comment: @jaychapani Again, ask yourself if that's reasonable.  It's not possible to perform such a security breach.

Comment: @Vulcan I am completely agree with you but this is what client is expecting. He says that this is possible that's why I just want the confirmation from all you expert. So I can prove my point.

Comment: @jaychapani It's not possible, make sure your client understands why as well :)

Comment: This is one of the most absurd questions with a security tag.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I have a legitimate need to disable this message. I don't want to disable for every site and publisher, but as a system admin I believe that I should have the option to specify a site and a publisher to bypass these messages. Say that a national education company decided to use java for a state wide assessment which shows this very message, it would be really nice if I could bypass the step to have to explain hundreds of second and third graders how to click on run to load their assessment, and then watch as some still click don't run.

Comment: @ppeterka  you run programs on your computer, that's what viruses do but it doesn't make your program a virus.  If the techie user can specify a website and says run applets on this website without prompting, then that'd be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot stop that warning from appearing.  It exists exactly for the purpose of preventing developers from doing what you're trying to do, as running executables without permission can be dangerous for the end user's system and personal data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose between uninstalling Java or using an older version. Otherwise you have to OK every single JSP page you ever use. Don't ever upgrade your Java because it will reset all of these warnings and you'll have to go through the process all over again. Our internal LAN uses a JSP application as a frontend to our Oracle database, and I have to check this box about 2 - 300 times every time Java is upgraded. I finally installed an older version. If Oracle was trying to make people even more averse to upgrading Java, good job.

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is to open a page, accept and run the application, then leave the page open. Add a new tab open the page again and you wont get the warnings.